# How to make Spring-ws work with Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, spring-ws, ws-security

I couldn't find information about how to make 
`org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor`
work with Kerberos.
I probably need to configure the interceptor and also the **securityPolicy.xml** file in some way.

I use ***spring-ws 2.0.2*** and ***spring 3.0.5*** (jdk6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spring sec extension for kerberos, did you try that one?

Comment: Looks like what i need. I just need to find out how to make it work with spring web services